# Which method is more efficient, Using DataTemplate of ListBox in XAML or populating ListBox at runtime?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I was using DataTemplate in a ListBox as XAML code earlier, I have recently modified my code and now at runtime I am populating the ListBox using foreach and other loops. 
(In this way I have more control for formatting and other manipulations.)

The problem is the efficiency of the code, which has decreased. It's taking 1 to 2 seconds more time now with loops than the Item/Data template in XAML earlier.
(Less control over code, lots of Bindings and converters, increasing complexity of the code which is not easy to manipulate.)

Kindly, suggest me

- Which way is more efficient way? and why?
- How can I still make solution with loops more efficient? Threading?
- Any friendly tutorial for learning Async threading? for non-native English speakers?

Thanks a lot and regards!

Comment: As an example, I am now using like this: (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11103693/1304247). Earlier this code was implemented in XAML.

Comment: Clever usage of template Triggers will do pretty much whatever you wanted to do by creating those items in C#, and it's much faster to boot.  Look up `Style`, `ControlTemplate`, and `DataTemplate` triggers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XAML parser is optimized to create the controls in the best way possible given the WPF layout system, further they allow for *virtualization* of the items, that means that the actual controls representing the items are only created when the item is visible.

Besides that i would *always* prefer a DataTemplate as it is declarative, easier to read and less code.

Comment: It means I should convert revert my changes!?

Comment: Accessing textBlocks at runtime, and making formatting is really difficult through XAML. So many converters need to be used. I read one article that we should avoid using converters and to keep the XAML as simple and clean as possible.

Comment: Bindings have a StringFormat property, and everything that goes beyond strings can be done via layout, if you use many converters you are probably doing something wrong.